# Will Ubuntu One delete or restore files in the cloud after formatting my PC?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, sync, format

One of PCs the Windows is having typically Windows issues and needs a reformat. I have my documents, pictures, music files etc syncing across Ubuntu One to access on Smartphone and my Ubuntu dedicated PC.

When I have reformatted PC, and install Ubuntu One. What will happen?

Will it sync my files to the PC, or will it delete the files and synchronize that there is nothing in the documents, music and picture folders.

Comment: The service is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

the goal of cloud services like dropbox, ubuntu one, ... is to prevent you from loosing data.so if you have uploaded your data in ubuntu one, it wouldn't loose your data because they are stored in canonical data centers.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is. If i just uploaded then downloaded files manually this would be absolutely the perfect answer. However this is more around the syncing ability of Ubuntu 1. In the past I had stored some pdfs in a synced folder with U1, by accident I deleted the folder they were in. Ahh they should still be on Ubuntu 1 and can redownload them, but what had happened is that the cloud folder had synced my delete and had removed them also. So with the considerable amount of documents, music, pictures have this time. Not looking for a repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Your files will not be deleted from the cloud. Obviously they are gone from the HD, but when you reinstall the Ubuntu One client, you can choose to sync the folders again to get them locally.

Ubuntu One will only delete the files in the cloud if you specifically go to the folder and choose delete while the client is running. By reformatting I assume you are doing it from a Windows cd or Ubuntu cd, and therefor the client won't be running, hence no deleted files.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. My concern was once I had reinstalled Windows 7 to be on the PC and installed the Ubuntu 1 client, it would sync that there was effectively empty documents, music, pictures etc. And the cloud would mirror this. 

Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Np. Hope our answers have been a help to clarify your concerns. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer(s) you like.